# Pymongo Regex match with list

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of distinct strings.

```
lst = ['.\*123.\*','.\*252.\*','.\*812.\*','.\*135.\*']
```

I want to perform an aggregation operation such that my $match looks like the following:

```
 {"$match":{"Var":{"$in":lst}}}
```

The var field in MongoDb records is a string containing numbers:
e.g. "abc123", "haaofalfa812", etc. I want to match this Var to a regular expression. If the variables in the lst were less, i could've done this...

```
{"$match":{"Var":{"$in":[re.compile('.*123.*'),re.compile('.*252.*'),re.compile('.*812.*')]}}}
```

But since it is a lst already initialized and contains a lot of elements, what should I do?

I tried the following but this doesn't work too...

```
{"$match":{"Var":{"$in":[re.compile(x for x in lst)]}}}
```

I get the following error for obvious reasons.

> TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list comprehension is wrong. I reckon what you wanted to do is this:

```
[re.compile(x) for x in lst]
```

That `TypeError` comes from trying to pass generator(`x for x in lst` statement) to `re.compile()`